# Classic ASP Outbound TLS 1.2

Tags: asp.net, ssl, tls1.2

We use a web API call to UPS to check address information.  They are requiring TLS 1.2 and the switch has broken our page.

```
<%

If ACTION="Verify" and ncSCountry="USA" and ncSState<>"PR" and ncSState<>"AA" and ncSState<>"AP" and ncSState<>"AE" then

    Dim sXML 

    sXML = "<?xml version='1.0'?>"
    sXML = sXML & "<AccessRequest xml:lang='en-US'>"
    sXML = sXML & "<AccessLicenseNumber>XXXXXX</AccessLicenseNumber>"
    sXML = sXML & "<UserId>XXXX</UserId>"
    sXML = sXML & "<Password>XXXX</Password>"
    sXML = sXML & "</AccessRequest>"
    sXML = sXML & "<?xml version='1.0'?>"
    sXML = sXML & "<AddressValidationRequest xml:lang='en-US'>"
    sXML = sXML & "<Request>"
    sXML = sXML & "<TransactionReference>"
    sXML = sXML & "<CustomerContext /><XpciVersion>1.0001</XpciVersion>"
    sXML = sXML & "</TransactionReference>"
    sXML = sXML & "<RequestAction>XAV</RequestAction>"
    sXML = sXML & "<RequestOption>1</RequestOption></Request>"
    sXML = sXML & "<MaximumListSize>1</MaximumListSize>"
    sXML = sXML & "<AddressKeyFormat>"
    sXML = sXML & "<ConsigneeName></ConsigneeName>"
    sXML = sXML & "<BuildingName></BuildingName>"
    sXML = sXML & "<AddressLine>" & ncSAddr1   & "</AddressLine>"
    sXML = sXML & "<AddressLine>" & ncSAddr2   & "</AddressLine>"
    sXML = sXML & "<AddressLine></AddressLine>"
    sXML = sXML & "<PoliticalDivision2>" & ncSCity & "</PoliticalDivision2>"
    sXML = sXML & "<PoliticalDivision1>" & ncSState & "</PoliticalDivision1>"
    sXML = sXML & "<PostcodePrimaryLow>" &  ncSZip   & "</PostcodePrimaryLow>"
    sXML = sXML & "<CountryCode>US</CountryCode>"
    sXML = sXML & "</AddressKeyFormat>"
    sXML = sXML & "</AddressValidationRequest>"


    'Now pass the request to UPS
    Dim xmlhttp4, sResponseXML, myDoc
    Set xmlhttp4 = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    'Set xmlhttp4 = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp4.Open "POST","https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/XAV", false
    xmlhttp4.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xmlhttp4.send(sXML)
    If xmlhttp4.Status >= 400 And xmlhttp4.Status <= 599 Then
        'Response.Write( "Error Occurred : " & xmlhttp.Status & " - " & xmlhttp.statusText)
        sResponseXML = "</empty>"
    Else
        sResponseXML = xmlhttp4.responseText
    End If

    Set myDoc=CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    myDoc.loadXML(sResponseXML)
    myDoc.async = false

    Dim addressline, addressline2, city, state, zip, zip4, responsestatus

    Dim root, NodeList, x
    Set root = myDoc.DocumentElement
    If myDoc.hasChildNodes then 
        Set NodeList = root.SelectNodes("AddressKeyFormat")
        For x = 0 To (NodeList.Length - 1)
            city = NodeList.Item(x).SelectSingleNode("PoliticalDivision2").Text
            state = NodeList.Item(x).SelectSingleNode("PoliticalDivision1").Text
            addressline = NodeList.Item(x).SelectSingleNode("AddressLine").Text

            addressline2=NodeList.Item(x).SelectSingleNode("AddressLine").NextSibling.nodename
            if addressline2="AddressLine" then
                addressline2=NodeList.Item(x).SelectSingleNode("AddressLine").NextSibling.Text
            Else
                addressline2=""
            ENd if

            zip = NodeList.Item(x).SelectSingleNode("PostcodePrimaryLow").Text
            zip4 = NodeList.Item(x).SelectSingleNode("PostcodeExtendedLow").Text
        Next
    End If

    Dim startcust3, endcust3
    startcust3=instr(sresponseXML, "<ResponseStatusCode>")
    endcust3 = instr(sresponseXML, "</ResponseStatusCode>")
    responsestatus=Mid(sResponseXML,startcust3+20,(endcust3-startcust3-20))

ENd if


%>
```

I have already tried to make this switch, but I feel like I am missing something.

```
Set xmlhttp4 = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
'Set xmlhttp4 = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
```

Comment: Try taking a look at the responses in this SO article: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29127018/964043

Comment: You've tried setting whatever HTTP client you're using to use TLS 1.2? I've read around that it may require .NET 4.5+ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137106/are-there-net-implementation-of-tls-1-2

Answer (score 20):

I found a solution with a simple registry fix.

1) Register TLS 1.2 Protocol:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
```

2) Configure TLS 1.2 to be default in 32 bit applications:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp]
"DefaultSecureProtocols"=dword:00000800
```

3) Configure TLS 1.2 to be default in 64 bit applications:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp]
"DefaultSecureProtocols"=dword:00000800
```

4) Restart server

**If you need support of TLS 1.1 only then:**

- On step 1) above simply change "TLS 1.2" to "TLS 1.1" and apply new registry fix
- On steps 2) and 3) above change value "00000800" to "00000200" and apply new registry fix

**If you need support of both TLS 1.1 and 1.2 then**

- Repeat step 1) from above two times two register both protocols
- On steps 2) and 3) use value "00000A00" (what is combination of "00000800" + "00000200")

**Code for verification:**

```
<%
Set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
objHttp.open "GET", "https://howsmyssl.com/a/check", False
objHttp.Send
Response.Write objHttp.responseText 
Set objHttp = Nothing 
%>
```

At the end of response you should see version of TLS used by request

```
"tls_version":"TLS 1.2"
```

Comment: This had no change for me. Using Windows 2008 R2, SP1. I still get the `The connection with the server was terminated abnormally ` error

Comment: I had issue on 1 of my servers when this fix didn't help.
I noticed that version of winhttp.dll is older there.
And I fixed it by installing KB3140245 - it updated that library:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3140245

Comment: I can confirm the above - that I needed to apply kb3140245 first from here http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb3140245, then apply the 'easy fix' and add the default keys they describe here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi . For me I added 512 (decimal) as the value to enable TLS1.1 as default. Then winhttp calls used TLS1.1 as default in code.