# WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1 does not work with PayPal sandbox after TLS 1.2

Tags: paypal, asp-classic, winhttp, tls1.2, winhttprequest

PayPal sandbox just recently restricted to TLS 1.2 connection.  This makes our site stop working with PayPal sandbox although it stills work with the production PayPal.  In the future the production PayPal will have the same restriction.  We're using classic ASP and Microsoft WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1 component for communication with PayPal.  Here's the code below.  objHttp.StatusText returns "Bad Request".  We're on Windows Server 2008 R2.  I tried to use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 instead, but it only works on my Windows 8.1 development machine, not on our Windows Server 2008 R2.  Although MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 is a superset of WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1, but it is less reliable than WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1.  Our code fails a few times a day using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 in the past, so I prefer using WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1.  I'm also not confident in this line of code: objHttp.Option(9) = &H0AA0 .  A workaround that we're using is calling the WebAPI for sending message to PayPal; however, this causes an extra minor delay.

```
dim objHttp
Set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
dim WinHttpRequestOption_EnableHttp1_1 : WinHttpRequestOption_EnableHttp1_1 = 17
objHttp.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableHttp1_1) = False

dim WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags : WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags=4
objHttp.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags) = &H3300
objHttp.setTimeouts 0, 120000, 120000, 120000 
objHttp.Option(9) = &H0AA0 '2720
objHttp.open "post", "" & "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/" & "", False
strRequest = SetExpressCheckoutSOAP(returnURL, cancelURL)
objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(strRequest)

objHttp.setRequestHeader "Host", "api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com"
Call objHttp.send(strRequest)
if objHttp.Status = 200 then
   resp = objHttp.responseText
else
   response.write objHttp.StatusText
end if
```

WebAPI invoke code:

```
dim webapiresp, webapidata
webapidata = "{""url"":""" & gv_APIEndpoint & """, ""message"":""" & nvpStrComplete & """,""soap"":0}"
webapiresp=InvokeWebAPI(strApiDomain, "POST", "comm/send", "", webapidata)
        set reply=JSON.parse(webapiresp)
        resp = reply.xml

Function InvokeWebAPI(strApiDomain, method, funcname, param, data)
dim HttpReq, apiURI, resp

set HttpReq=Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
'apiURI=strApiDomain & funcname & param
apiURI=strApiDomain & "api/" & funcname & param


HttpReq.open method, apiURI, false

HttpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
HttpReq.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", apiURI
HttpReq.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64Encode("xxx:xxx")

if data <> "" then
    HttpReq.send data
else
    HttpReq.send 
end if

resp = HttpReq.responseText

set HttpReq=Nothing

InvokeWebAPI = resp
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

My application is written in ASP classic and I use `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1`in place of `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0`. to post to paypal sandbox url.

What works for me is telling the `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 objec` to use TLS 1.2:

Set

```
httpRequest = Server.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
httpRequest.option (9) = 2720
```

All that on Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 2):

This option:

```
httpRequest.option (9) = 2720
```

Works only in Windows 2012 and newer

System library "winhttp.dll" of Windows 2008 R2 has only record for TLS 1.0 what equal to:

```
httpRequest.option (9) = 128
```

The other values will drop an exception.

But I found a solution which requires only changes in registry, without any additional changes in code.
See details here:
[Classic ASP Outbound TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997849/classic-asp-outbound-tls-1-2/39170683#39170683)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, but rather than setting `option(9)` a.k.a `WinHttpRequestOption_SecureProtocols` I needed to add support for TLS 1.2 in WinHttp itself

See article below, where you can run "Easy Fix" or add registry keys manually

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in

Answer (score 0):

First you need to enable support for TLS 1.2 on the server (I prefer to use the free [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) tool from [Nartac Software](https://www.nartac.com))

Then you can change the default behaviour by the setting following registry key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp]
"DefaultSecureProtocols"=dword:00000800
```

If you are using 32 bit applications, you also need this key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp]
"DefaultSecureProtocols"=dword:00000800
```