# An error occurred in the secure channel support in Windows 10 using Excel VBA WinHttpRequest

Tags: excel, vba

Using WinHttpRequest to check whether a able to connect to a remote server.
Code was working earlier however recently getting following error:

> "An error occurred in the secure channel support"

tested in Excel 2016 32bit, in Windows 10.

Gone though similar issues, it seems TLS 1.2 is not enabled. However also states in Windows 10 it is enabled by default. Not getting exact place how to check whether it is enabled or not or is the issue is because of this.

[VBA: An error occurred in the secure channel support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045305/vba-an-error-occurred-in-the-secure-channel-support)
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4040243/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-for-configuration-manager
https://www.itnota.com/enabling-tls-1-2-default-security-protocol-windows-servers/

```
 
    Dim request As New WinHttpRequest

    On Error GoTo ConnectionError
    request.Open "GET", url
    request.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + sEncryptedPassword
    request.Send
    IsConnectionAvailable = request.Status
```

Expected output to be connection should be successful, however getting error
"An error occurred in the secure channel support"