# VBA Read URL fails with "An error occured in the secure channel support" after website move to TLS1.3

Tags: vba, tls1.3

I am using Windows 10

This question is identical to [VBA: An error occurred in the secure channel support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045305/vba-an-error-occurred-in-the-secure-channel-support) but with TLS1.3 and not TLS1.2, and also @KarlH7's solution did not work for me.

```
Function ReadURLIntoString(url)
    Dim url As String
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim responseText As String

    ' Create a new instance of MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
   
    ' Open a GET request to the URL
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", url, False

    ' Send the request
    xmlhttp.send

    ' Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
    If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then
        ' Get the response text
        responseText = xmlhttp.responseText
        ' Now, responseText contains the contents of the URL

        'remove line breaks
        ReadURLIntoString = Trim(Replace(Replace(responseText, Chr(10), ""), Chr(13), ""))
    Else
        ' If the request was not successful, handle the error
        MsgBox "Error: " & xmlhttp.Status & " - " & xmlhttp.StatusText
    End If
End Function
```

The VBA reads a code from a website.

After I moved the website to TLS 1.3 (using CloudFlare) then this VBA fails at `.send` with the error **Run-time error '-2147012739 (80072f7d)': An error occurred in the secure channel support**

I tried the following with no success

1. using different libraries such as `Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")`and experimenting with `xmlhttp.setOption(2)=...`
2. Opening the Control Panel and selecting `Internet Properties/Security/Use TLS 1.3 (Experimental)` and rebooting.
3. Changing the registry to set `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Client\Enabled`=1 as per [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/working-vba-tls-protocol-srinath-gudimetla/) and [here](https://www.asustor.com/en/knowledge/detail/?id=&group_id=1011) and rebooting.

Any ideas?