# Can no longer call ASMX service from Classic ASP after TLS 1.2

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, asmx, application-pool

We have a web site that is primarily Webforms, but still contains a body of pages written in Classic ASP, sharing a directory structure. Those classic pages use the asmx services on the asp.net side to pull connection information.  This has been working adequately for years, until recently with our upgrade to TLS 1.2.  Now we get the following error on the **xmlhttp.send DataToSend** statement.

msxml3.dll error '80072efe' 
The connection with the server was terminated abnormally

My research says that this is the result of calling one Classic page from another Classic page when they occupy the same process or application pool.   But I am calling an ASP.NET ASMX Service, which is a different process and pool...right?

Short of rewriting the classic pages, how do I fix this issue?

> .NET Framework 4.5.2
>
> IIS 7.5.7600.16385
>
> Windows Server 2008 R2

```
Dim xmlhttp
Dim DataToSend
DataToSend="OrigId=XXXXX&OrigPassword=YYYYYY&ConnectionName=" & pConnectionName
Dim postUrl
postUrl = "https://" & Request.ServerVariables("server_name") & "/SSLWebServices/ConnectionLookUp.asmx/GetConnectionData"
Set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.setOption 2,13056
xmlhttp.Open "POST",postUrl,false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

xmlhttp.send DataToSend

dim strResponse
strResponse = xmlhttp.responseText
```

Comment: Have you installed [Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3140245)](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb3140245) ? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997849/classic-asp-outbound-tls-1-2/39170683#39170683

Answer (score 2):

The answer was at
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in. We had to add the DefaultSecureProtocols with a value of 0x00000800 to both the 64 and the 32 bit WinHttp registry keys.  It's all detailed in the support article.