# Unable to contact web service with msxml3.dll error

Tags: windows, web-services, ssl, vbscript

I am having issues on 2 machines *(both on seperate networks)* that are unable to access my web service. **The service works perfectly on every other machine and network I have tried** which rules out any firewall configurtaion.

---

**Call from SQL or vbs script reports**

```
msxml3.dll: The connection with the server was terminated abnormally  

Error: 80072efe
```

---

**Internet Explorer**

Incidently the **root** of the site is not accessible with Intenet explorer (On the problem servers **only**), however works fine in Both Edge and Chrome.

[image]

The certificate is hosted and restricted to TLS 1.2+ And is enabled in IE.

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to  use IE at all? It's completely unsupported.

Comment: @Larnu I am not trying to use IE. I am just pointing out that the site doesn't resolve consistantly in that browser on the problem machines which leads me to believe there is a correlation to the service call and IE configuration.

Comment: Would help if you stated what Windows Server versions you are using anything before Windows Server 2008 R2 is sketchy.

Comment: It works fine in both Chrome and Edge because at the heart of it they are the same browser engine (Chromium) and they implement their own version of the cipher suites instead of relying on the system cipher suites, so while it appears to work it can be misleading. See [TLS 1.2 Support added to Windows Server 2008](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2017/07/20/tls-1-2-support-added-to-windows-server-2008/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can no longer call ASMX service from Classic ASP after TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391487/can-no-longer-call-asmx-service-from-classic-asp-after-tls-1-2)

Comment: @user692942 Server is 2012RT. I was concluding this was likely a TLS issue. I will patch the server and see. Thanks for the find.

Comment: Windows Server 2012 should be okay, but like you say maybe an update is required.

Comment: @user692942 Unfortunately that didn't resolve it however having checked on multiple servers it does seem isolated to pre 2012 builds so I suspect it still might be missing ciphers.