# Does MSXML2.XMLHTTP object support TLS 1.2 (VBA/EXCEL)?

Tags: xml, vba

My client sent me this reminder:
*"We advised last August that we are intending to stop support for TLS 1.0 and we recommend that you move your software applications to use TLS 1.2 or higher."*

**Now, I don't know if I need to update the tool.**

As they share the tool to thousands of people there is no standard of the environment. For example, there are people using WIN 7 + Office 2010, there are people using WIN 10 + Office 365 ...

```vb
Dim objXmlHttp As Object
Set objXmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

objXmlHttp.Open "GET", sXML, False

'Create headings
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json" '"text/xml; charset=utf-8"
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", SoapActionUrl
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json"
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & Sheet3.Range("h9").Value
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Gov-Client-Connection-Method", "DESKTOP_APP_DIRECT"

'Send XML command
objXmlHttp.send objDom.XML
```

I tested but I couldn't find errors, but maybe, as I am using WIN 10 + Office 365 I have all my libraries up-to-date.

I just read that the `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` library would solve it. But I am not sure.

So, do I need to change anything?

Comment: I don't think `MSXML2` has seen an update this century, which makes it rather unlikely to support the newer protocols. Have you tried referencing this `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` library and using it?

Comment: I did try to use `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` and it worked. As I couldn't see the difference I don't know if I would have to change my code to start using `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` or not. But I think will be safer to use `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1`. Cheers!

Comment: [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997849/classic-asp-outbound-tls-1-2/39170683#39170683) something about patching TLS version, also there is the link from that answer, showing current supported version by client: [https://howsmyssl.com/a/check](https://howsmyssl.com/a/check)